# Haskell, tuple (double, string)

Tags: haskell, tuples

i need a little help.

Input : (double, string) tuple

Output:
 - in new lines the strings + ":"  + " " + 15% increased real number, at the end in new line "Done"

Example:

> myPutStr [(210.0,"Converse"),(315.0,"Crocs"),(250.0,"Lacoste"),(275.5,"Under Armour")]

Output:

Converse: 241.0

Crocs: 362.0

Lacoste: 287.0

Under Armour: 316.825

Done

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? What is your expected output is it different than the example. Do you have code you've created so far that you can share?

Comment: The output is correct for the actual example that i wrote before. I have a tuple(double, string) and i have to write out in new lines the answer in the following order : (strings: double(value) +15%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it using [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_)/[`traverse_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_) or the flipped argument versions: [`forM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:forM_)/[`for_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:for_). I prefer `for_` since it looks more like the "enhanced for-loop" from languages like Java.

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)

myPutStr :: [(Double,String)] -> IO ()
myPutStr vals = do
    for_ vals $ \(num, str) -> do
        putStr str
        putStr ": "
        print (num * 1.15) -- increase num by 15%
    putStrLn "Done"
```